# Replacing contents of hrefs not prefix with http and https

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

What I want to do is to replace href="..." with href="abc/...".
Except that when ... is http:// and https://

I have successfully done the first part, but I could not find a way to detect http:// and https://,
following is the codes:

```
line='<a href="img/a.html"/>'
print re.sub(r'href="([^<#][^"]*)"',r'href="abc/\1"', line)
//Correct Output: <a href="abc/img/a.html"/>

line='<a href="http://google.com"/>'
print re.sub(r'href="([^<#][^"]*)"',r'href="abc/\1"', line)
//WrongOutput: <a href="abc/http://google.com"/>
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the second one?

Comment: It seems like you're manipulating HTML with regex. A nice read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/948550 . Can you port the task to something that's meant to parse HTML like: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ ?

Comment: Are you guaranteed it starts with <a href=" ?  If so, just check whether the next are http:// or https://  If it is, leave it.  If it's not, add abc

Comment: don't use regex to parse html.

Answer (score 2):

Through [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc),

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = """<a href="img/a.html"/>
<a href="http://google.com"/>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> for i in soup.select('a'):
        if re.match(r'(?!https?://)', i['href']):
            i['href'] = 'abc/' + i['href']


>>> print(soup)
<html><body><a href="abc/img/a.html"></a>
<a href="http://google.com"></a></body></html>
```

**OR**

No, need for regex here.

```
>>> for i in soup.select('a'):
        if not i['href'].startswith('http://') or i['href'].startswith('https://'):
            i['href'] = 'abc/' + i['href']


>>> print(soup)
<html><body><a href="abc/img/a.html"></a>
<a href="http://google.com"></a></body></html>
```

**OR**

```
>>> for i in soup.select('a'):
        if not i['href'].startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
            i['href'] = 'abc/' + i['href']


>>> soup
<html><body><a href="abc/img/a.html"></a>
<a href="http://google.com"></a></body></html>
```

Comment: simple `if "https" in i['href']`  of if `i['href'].startswith("https")` does away with any need for regex

Comment: You can remove some indentation and factor out regex here... `for i in soup('a', href=lambda L: not L.startswith(('http://', 'https://'))):`...

Comment: @AvinashRaj if you're going with `.startswith` - note that it takes a tuple as per my comment - saves the `or` and typing out `i['href'].startswith` twice...

Answer (score 0):

You can use look arounds as

```
>>> line='<a href="img/a.html"/>'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=href=")(?!https?)',r'abc/', line)
'<a href="abc/img/a.html"/>'

>>> line='<a href="http://google.com"/>'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=href=")(?!https?)',r'abc/', line)
'<a href="http://google.com"/>'
```

- `(?<=href=")` positive look behind checks if the string position is presceded by `href="`
- `(?!https?)` negative look ahead. Checks if the position, after the `href="` is **not** followed by  `http` or `https`

Answer (score -1):

This is for those who can port their task to HTML-parsing libraries (like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/))

```
import bs4

# this adds some content to create a valid doc, we'll ignore it
# since we don't need it
element = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<a href="img/a.html"/>')
print element

element.a['href'] = 'abc/' + element.a['href']
# link has changed - print element tag
print element.a

# to get the string simply cast to string
print str(element.a)
# prints: <a href="abc/img/a.html"></a>
```

Bonus read on [parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: while beautifulsoup is a much better option to parse html, your code does not answer the question